# How can I remove certain elements from XML using SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I load the following XML data into SimpleXML like this:

```php
<?php
$xmlString = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
    <item key="0">
        <title>AH 2308</title>
        <field_a>3.00</field_a>
        <field_b>7.00</field_b>
        <field_d1>35.00</field_d1>
        <field_d2>40.00</field_d2>
        <field_e></field_e>
        <field_g2></field_g2>
        <field_g>M 45x1,5</field_g>
        <field_gewicht>0.13</field_gewicht>
        <field_gtin>4055953012781</field_gtin>
        <field_l>40.00</field_l>
        <field_t></field_t>
        <field_abdrueckmutter>KM 9</field_abdrueckmutter>
        <field_sicherung>MB 7</field_sicherung>
        <field_wellenmutter>KM 7</field_wellenmutter>
    </item>
    <item key="1">
        <title></title>
        <field_a></field_a>
        <field_b></field_b>
        <field_d1></field_d1>
        <field_d2></field_d2>
        <field_e></field_e>
        <field_g2></field_g2>
        <field_g></field_g>
        <field_gewicht></field_gewicht>
        <field_gtin></field_gtin>
        <field_l></field_l>
        <field_t></field_t>
        <field_abdrueckmutter></field_abdrueckmutter>
        <field_sicherung></field_sicherung>
        <field_wellenmutter></field_wellenmutter>
    </item>
</response>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

How can I achieve the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
    <item key="0">
        <title>AH 2308</title>
        <field_a>3.00</field_a>
        <field_b>7.00</field_b>
        <field_d1>35.00</field_d1>
        <field_d2>40.00</field_d2>
        <field_e></field_e>
        <field_g2></field_g2>
        <field_g>M 45x1,5</field_g>
        <field_gewicht>0.13</field_gewicht>
        <field_gtin>4055953012781</field_gtin>
        <field_l>40.00</field_l>
        <field_t></field_t>
        <field_abdrueckmutter>KM 9</field_abdrueckmutter>
        <field_sicherung>MB 7</field_sicherung>
        <field_wellenmutter>KM 7</field_wellenmutter>
    </item>
    <item key="1"></item>
</response>
```

To delete all empty elements, I could use the following working code:

```php
foreach ($xml->xpath('/child::*//*[not(*) and not(text()[normalize-space()])]') as $emptyElement) {
    unset($emptyElement[0]);
}
```

But that's not exactly what I want.

Basically, when the `<title>` element is empty, I want to remove it with all its siblings and keep the parent `<item>` element.

**What's important:** I also want to keep empty element, if the `<title>` is not empty. See `<item key="0">` for example. The elements `<field_e>`, `<field_g2>` and `<field_t>`will be left untouched.

Is there an easy xpath query which can achieve that? Hope anyone can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried and what errors you are getting. Also please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This xpath query is working:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//title[not(text()[normalize-space()])]/following-sibling::*') as $emptyElement) {
    unset($emptyElement[0]);
}
```

It keeps the `<title>` element but I can live with that.

Answer (score 0):

DOM is more flexible manipulating nodes:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$expression = '/response/item[not(title[normalize-space()])]';

foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $emptyItem) {
    // replace children with an empty text node
    $emptyItem->textContent = '';
}

echo $document->saveXML();
```